# how to debug 'page not rendering' in magento 2- possible problem with the xml

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, render

How do you debug a page in a custom module. or more to the point. How do you debug whether the xml is rending the correct page content.

I am trying to create a page in my custom module, I am able to create the page but its content is blank.

I believe that the problem relates to the xml because if I do a `vardump` on the controller it renders an output. this means that the problem relates to the xml output.

below are my files-- I would really appriate any advice on how I can go out debugging the problem.

**=> Block :**

```
namespace Lsg\Authunpw\Block;

class PostList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,

        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    //    $this->_postCollectionFactory = $postCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [\Lsg\Authunpw\Model\Customer::CACHE_TAG . '_' . 'list'];
    }

}
```

**Fronend xml :**

> Lsg\Authunpw\etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="auths" frontName="auths">
            <module name="Lsg_Authunpw" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Frontend view :**

> authunpw_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Lsg\Authunpw\Block\PostList" name="auths.list" template="Lsg_Authunpw::list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento identifies the handler from the url. So if you have defined routes as **auths** and calling it from **index** method and action then your handler should be `auths_index_index.xml`

Rename your **xml file** from

```
authunpw_index_index.xml
```

To

```
auths_index_index.xml
```

Comment: thank you so much. i have been on this issue for a week now